# nuget package manager out of sync

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I am on Nuget 2.5.4. The 'Manage packages for entire solution' feature to install Updates is intermittently showing 'false positives'.

By false positive, I mean an indication that something in the solution needs an update, BUT every project in the solution is already at the latest update. At least I *think* that is what is going on.

For example (see below), nuget is offering to help install NUnit but every package is grayed out. The test projects *should* be grayed out since they are already at the latest release.

Packages without NUnit are also grayed out though, and I would think they should not be, so the solution manager can install them. So not sure if my false positive theory is correct, but *something* is out of sync.

What is the fix?

Cheers,

[image]

[image]

Comment: My source control sometimes locks the config files such that my `web.config` and `packages.config` are sometimes out of sync after a NuGet update.

Comment: @Jasen. How do you re-synch when that happens?

Comment: The `output` window that normally displays build events will show what usually went wrong with a NuGet update/install. Most of the time releasing the readonly on the config files then doing another update will fix the config files. Otherwise, I have to remove and reinstall some packages.

Answer (score 19):

From the output of `Process Monitor` it seems that the solution wide updates are determined based on the contents of the `Packages` folder that is under the root of the solution:

It scans the folder and checks for updates for all of the packages that have been downloaded there, and it will display that there's an update for an old package even if the newer package is also there.

So in order to sync this, you should clear this folder, and then restore the packages of your solution. After that, the next time you open this dialog, it will show the correct results.

Answer (score 12):

Go directly to the packages physical directory for the solution, something like C:\projects\\packages.

Ensure that the false positives do not have older versions in this directory alongside the current versions.

Answer (score 1):

My source control sometimes locks the config files such that my `web.config` and `packages.config` are sometimes out of sync after a NuGet update.

The `output` window that normally displays build events will show what usually went wrong with a NuGet update/install.

Most of the time releasing the readonly on the config files then doing another update will fix the config files. If that doesn't work I have to remove and re-install some packages.

**Edit:** Depending on your project type you may not have a web.config and not all packages write to the app config settings.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see a web.config. I do have packages.config in the Nuget folder along with the Nuget.targets and the exe. Not sure I know what you mean by release readonly. I am using svn here.

Comment: I tried removing and reinstalling NUnit on one project, which I can do at the solution level. It didn't clean up the update situation though.

Comment: web.config and packages.config is under each project node.

Comment: My source control should release the readonly file lock, but sometimes with a NuGet update it does not and I need to manually check out the config files.

Answer (score 0):

Much later but mentioning in case somebody else comes along. Running NuGet 2.8.x, I was encountering much the same issue with the package manager GUI (go to console to update and it states each package latest).

To resolve, I cleaned out my projects packages directory (except of course the repositories.config file) which in turn revealed that there was a NuGet version conflict: in the root of my solution, the .nuget directory contained an outdated NuGet.exe. I deleted the .nuget directory, rebuilt, and now we're again good to go (all packages downloaded and in package manager only packages with updates are showing).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was closing Visual Studio and to delete all content from the `/packages` folder. You could also delete all subfolders from `/packages` that are listed in the update list of NuGet that are the false positives.